# Adiabatic Invariant when forcing is at the natural frequency of a classical simple harmonic oscillator

Tags: classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, hamiltonian-formalism, adiabatic, invariants

Consider a simple harmonic oscillator of unit mass, natural frequency $\omega_0$, given by the Hamiltonian
\begin{align}
  H_0(q,p)=\frac{1}{2} \left[ p^2 + \omega_0^2 q^2 \right] \ .
\end{align}
Now imagine changing the natural frequency slowly i.e the Hamiltonian becomes,
\begin{align}
  H(q,p,t)=\frac{1}{2} \left[ p^2 + \omega(t)^2 q^2 \right] \ ,
\end{align}
where $\omega(t)$ is a slowly varying function of time, with $\omega(0)=\omega_0$ (A well known example is slowly changing the length of a simple pendulum). Then we know that the action variable,
\begin{align}
  I(t) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \oint d q \; p = \frac{H(t)}{\omega(t)} 
\end{align}
is approximately a constant.
More precisely, if
\begin{align}
  \frac{1}{\omega^2} \frac{d \omega}{dt} = \epsilon \ll 1 \ ,
\end{align}
Then it can be shown (see, for example, Arnold's "Mathematical methods of classical mechanics",  Sec 52 E, p 298-300) that the change in $H/\omega$ is $O(\epsilon)$ over time intervals $0< t < (\omega_0 \epsilon)^{-1}$.

With this context, my question is the following: Let us assume $\omega(t)^2$ is sinusoidal i.e  $\omega(t)^2 = \omega_0^2 (1 + \epsilon \sin(\nu t))$. If the frequency associated with the change of $\omega$ is the same as the natural frequency $\omega_0$ i.e $\nu = \omega_0$, then is adiabatic invariance broken? If so, what is the implicit assumption made for adiabatic invariance, that is violated in this case.

In Arnold's book, "Geometrical methods methods in the theory of ODEs", Sec 20 , p 170-171, he has a discussion on the issue being tricky in case of multiple natural frequencies which are resonant. However my question concerns a system with a single natural frequency that is driven at the same frequency, hence it is not clear to me how that discussion is applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

It is not really an external resonant force, but a parametric time dependence. When the epsilon is small, the criterium is good and the frequency stays the same, I guess (even though the amplidute may vary).

Comment: But when we change the length of a pendulum, we apply a force, right? I mean Newton's 3rd law takes the form $\ddot q + \omega_0^2 q + \epsilon \omega_0^2 q \sin \nu t = 0$, so the third term is a time and co-ordinate dependent forcing.

Comment: But the las two terms is just $\omega^2(t)\approx \omega_0^2$. You may apply a WKB approximation to solve this equation, no?

Comment: In fact, I have dealt with such equations; you may read my papers about this subject: https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.3504  and   https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.03021