# Why is the action an adiabatic invariant in a unidimensional oscillator?

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, adiabatic, invariants

I'm reading Rax's "Méchanique Analytique" but I can't understand a particular step.
We consider a unidimensional oscillator system  with a potential that depends on a parameter $\lambda(t)$ varying very slowly with time.
Given a Hamiltonian
$$H\left(p,q,\lambda\right)=\frac{p^{2}}{2}+U\left(q,\lambda\right) ,$$
we're trying to prove that the "action variable", defined as the Maupertuis action over one cycle is adiabatically constant.
It is stated that if we consider a movement $p\left(q,E,\lambda\right)$ with $\lambda$ almost fixed ans $E$ being the energy, then we have $$\frac{\partial H}{\partial\lambda}\mid_{H=E}+\frac{\partial H}{\partial p}\mid_{H=E}\frac{\partial p}{\partial\lambda}=0.$$
I do not understand why this equation is true.
I understand that the total energy is almost constant and therefore the total derivative of the Hamiltonian with respect to time is approximately zero, but if I follow this idea, the equation I get also has a term for the partial derivative if the Hamiltonian with respect to the position variable $q$ in addition to the $p$ and $\lambda$ terms given above.

Comment: See Landau & Lifshitz, vol.1 $\S49$. Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/619072/2451